# Use AS3 to parse XML node attribute that has a colon

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, parsing, ttml

I have the following XML document:

```
<tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling" xml:lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<div xml:lang="it">
<p begin="00:00:00" end="00:00:02" style="violet">first</p>
</div>
</body>
</tt>
```

I load the contents into my flash object using AS3 successfully.  But how do print/trace the value of the attribute in `<div xml:lang="it">`?  When I try the code:

```
trace(myxml.children()[1].children()[0].@xml:lang);
```

The compiler complains about the syntax error presented by the colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your xml there is no 'xml' namespace. Probably you missed it. Should be something like this:

```
<tt xmlns:xml="http://blabla.com" ... xml:lang="en">
```

Then you need to declare [Namespace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Namespace.html) instance for accessing xml attributes, tags for that namespace:

```
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("xml","http://blabla.com") ;
```

Then you can use this code to access attribute:

```
trace(myxml.children()[1].children()[0].@ns::lang);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use:
`.attribute('xml:lang') instead of .@xml:lang`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#attribute()

Comment: No more syntax error, but i'm also getting no output now.  If I do a trace(myxml.children()[1].children()[0]), then the output is `<div xml:lang="it">
<p begin="00:00:00" end="00:00:02" style="violet">first</p>
</div>` .  Any ideas?

Comment: trace(myxml.children()[1].children()[0].attribute("xml:lang")) gives me nothing.  I also try adding more attibutes to the div element, and none of them print from the .attribute() function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `::`.

```
.@xml::lang
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6c.html