# How to parse XML attribute like this "drools:version"?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, xml-parsing, e4x

I have the next xml element:

```
<bpmn2:process id="Process_1" drools:version="1" drools:packageName="defaultPackage" drools:adHoc="false" name="MyNewProcess" isExecutable="true">
<bpmn2:startEvent id="StartEvent_1" name="Start1">
  <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1</bpmn2:outgoing>
</bpmn2:startEvent>
<bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1" drools:priority="1" name="SF1" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="Task_1"/>
<bpmn2:endEvent id="EndEvent_1" name="End1">
  <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_2</bpmn2:incoming>
</bpmn2:endEvent>
```

I'm parsing it using ActionScript3.0, how to get the 'drools:version' attribute value?

I can get the id myXML.child(0).@id but I can NOT get myXML.child(0).@drools:version !!!
How I can do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use AS3 to parse XML node attribute that has a colon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911534/use-as3-to-parse-xml-node-attribute-that-has-a-colon)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the ability to test but have you tried using square brackets?

```
myXML.child(0)['drools:version']
```

following on from the example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656469/as3-namespace-get-an-attribute-with-a-minus-sign-in-it)